# How to Identify mentions in a text?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am looking for rule-based methods or any other methods to identify all mentions in a text. I have found several libraries that give coreferences but no exact options for only mentions. What I want is something like below:

Input text:

> [This painter]'s indulgence of visual fantasy, and appreciation of different historic architectural styles can be seen in his 1840 Architect's Dream. After a series of paintings on The Last of the Mohicans, [he] made a three year trip to Europe in 1829, but [he] is better known for a trip four years earlier in which [he] journeyed up the Hudson River to the Catskill Mountains. FTP, name [this painter of The Oxbow] and The Voyage of Life series.

*The square brackets highlight mentions.

How do I find mentions? Also, how is it different from coreferences? It would be really helpful if someone could post links to the concerned papers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get what you want from the standard `dcoref` annotator. Look at the annotation set by this annotator, [`CorefChainAnnotation`](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/dcoref/CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation.html). This is a map from document entities to "coref chains."

Each [`CorefChain`](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/dcoref/CorefChain.html) can provide you with a list of mentions for the relevant entity in textual order.